# Speeding up VM performance

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a Mid-2012 MacBook Pro, that has an Intel Core i7-3651QM @ 2.30GHz, with 16GB 1600Mhz DDR3 memory and a SSD running VMWare Fusion for doing development work with.  The VM runs almost as smoothly as the host and I have no problems.   I also have a desktop with an i7-870 2.93GhZ, with 8GB and a ATI Radeon HD 5450 running VMWare Workstation 8

I configured a VM with 4GB of memory, but when I run it on the desktop it's terribly slow.  The networking is orders of magnitude slower running in the guest than it is the host.  When I try to use a GUI IDE, it is very laggy and sometimes there are artifacts from being rendered improperly.   Looking at the the System performance on the host, I'm only using 7 of my 8 GB of memory, so I don't think it's because of swapping on the host.  Any suggestions as to how I can increase the performance in the guest VM on the desktop?  I've already got VMWare tools installed as it was installed as part of the easy install process (Ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: Is the hardware virtualization support turned on in the Desktop's BIOS?

Comment: Yes it is (at least it used to be)

Comment: Has the Ubuntu VM ever functioned properly?  I'd guess Ubuntu 13.10 isn't fully compatible with VMWare Workstation 8.

Comment: It's my first install of 13.10, but I've noticed that my other VM's are noticeably slower on the desktop, whereas on the laptop I can barely tell the difference.